# Flutter passing boolean argument in getx route

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-routes

I have two getx controllers 1 register and 2 home. I need to pass a boolean argument to home to notify if the user is registering first time.

on registration controller

```
// here's how iam trying to pass an argument using route

  Get.offAllNamed('/home',arguments: true);
```

on home controller

```
  final _isNewUserRegistration = false.obs;
  bool get isNewUserRegistration => _isNewUserRegistration.value;  // bool variable to check if the user is newly registered
```

and on oninit of homecontroller i'm trying to assign the argument to _isNewUserRegistration.

```
   @override
   void onInit(){
    super.onInit();
   _isNewRegistration(Get.arguments);
   }
```

But I couldn't get the argument value from the previous controller. How can I get the value passed from the previous controller to the current controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Get.offAllNamed('/home',parameters: {"boolean":true});
```

On Home Controller

```
final _isNewUserRegistration = false.obs;


 @override
   void onInit(){
    super.onInit();
   _isNewRegistration(Get.parameters['boolean']);
   }
```

or try also this

```
final _isNewUserRegistration = Get.parameters['boolean']; // or with obs
```

mention me if its working

Comment: I also was looking for your post here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187574/send-data-through-arguments-with-getx :)

Comment: @Arbiter Chil Not getting the value to second controller. only passing  null

Comment: can we move this on chat or move to call? hmm try to  _isNewUserRegistration = "".obs change the to string and also the  pass boolean "true"  to string if its working

Comment: @Arbiter Chil I passed the argument as string and checked it on the second controller.

Comment: I am having doubts, the type of parameters is Map<String, String>. Then how is this possible ? I am getting error when passing bool.

Comment: i think u should pass only string on this point since it Map <String, String>